# Emailing text attachment with Python 2.7 via Gmail almost working

Tags: email, python-2.7, gmail, text-files, email-attachments

So I'm working on a script that will generate a text file based on a MYSQL database *and* email the file as an attachement via gmail. I've almost got everything working but the file it attaches, while named correctly, shows up as being blank. I've poked around the documentation and many questions here (that's how I was able to get as far as I have) but can't quite suss out where my particular mistake is. I'm dead certain it's something obvious but after working with this for the last 7 hours, I can't see it. I'm not new to programming but I *am* new to both python and to working with emails programattically so that's probably also part of the problem. Anyway, here is the file in question. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. As an aside I want to thank everyone here for the help I've gotten in the past when I was working on an Android app. I was able to get everything working and get it published in the store. =)

(I've edited my credentials here for both database login and email login to be fake values)

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys, time, datetime

import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email import Encoders
import os

try:
#   prompt = ('> ')

t = time.localtime()

fp = file('bus_rep_%s-%s-%s--%s.%s.%s.txt' % (t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]), 'a+')
fp.write("Business Name\t\tEIN\t\tSub Date\tDays\tAction\n")
con = mdb.connect('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'USERNAME', 'USERPASS', 'DBNAME');

#   print "Enter start date: YYYY-MM-DD"
start_date = 2000-01-01

cur = con.cursor()

current_date = datetime.date.today()
#   print "Current Date = %r" % current_date
cur.execute('SELECT BusName, EIN, DWHDateSubmitted FROM Business WHERE DWHSubmitted LIKE %d AND DWHDateSubmitted IS NOT NULL' % (1))
# Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
results = cur.fetchall()

for row in results:
    bname = row[0]
    ein = row[1]
    subdate = row[2]

#       print bname
#       print ein
#       print subdate

    days_passed = current_date - subdate
    days_passed = days_passed.days
#       print "days_passed = %r" % days_passed

    if days_passed > 30:
        action = 'Contact Claims'
    else:
        action = ' '

#       print "bname = %s, EIN = %s, subdate = %s, days_passed = %d, action = %s" % (bname, ein, subdate, days_passed, action )

    fp.write("%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%s\n" % (bname, ein, subdate, days_passed, action ))
except mdb.Error, e:
print "Error: %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.arge[1])
sys.exit(1)

con.close()

gmail_user = "USER@GMAIL.com"
gmail_pwd = "GMAILPASS"

def mail(to, subject, text, attach):
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = gmail_user
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(open(attach, 'r').read())
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
        'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(attach))
msg.attach(part)

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg.as_string())

mailServer.close()

mail("email@fakesite.com",
"Daily Business Claim Submission Report",
"Attached is the automatically generated Daily Business Claim Report.",
"bus_rep_%s-%s-%s--%s.%s.%s.txt" % (t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out where I'd messed up. I'd forgotten to actually close the file once I was done writing to it. I simply put the fp.close() after where I close the connection to the database con.close() and it emails the file no problem.